# Managing GPG keys for clusters of servers

Tags: encryption, automation, gnupg

I want hands-off management of root password change.
admins use sudo su for root access so the root password is never used on a day to day basis
Im planning to "save" the password in the far-reaching emergency that someone actually needs it

Typically this is a manual admin task and the password is kept in a digital safe (this effort is to eliminate that)

use case
automate root password change across  1 cluster of 20 servers

pseudo  code

generate gpg keys across 20 nodes via ssh
using technique here https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html

each node then has ~/.gnupg dir with keys

next this-is-scripted.sh

generate a secure password for root
write the password to file
change roots password
encrypt file

I run this script on 20 nodes, its changes the password, encrypts the password file and I can decrypt the file.

So at this point, all is good...

My question is, to get this to scale better, how can I "import" all the keys from each server, into each server (think within cluster1)?

the use case I need to decrypt the password file for server 13  which is not available or the configuration is damaged.

Specifically
how can I identify each server say 1 through 20 from gpg command line (keyring??)
then say from any server in the cluster decrypt the password file from server 13
and or how to have a "keyring" that is aware of the other keys within the cluster

I know gpg is primarily for email, but Id like to use it for password file encryption

Hopefully, this makes sense to someone :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since no replies... but I get a lot from StackOverflow so i figured out my solution and posting it here...

a couple of things I could go while creating the initial keys

```
runonall() {
for node in `cat /your/list/of/servers.txt`
do ssh root@node "$1"
done
}
```

runonall 'mkdir -p /shared/nas/gpg/$(hostname)'

runonall 'gpg --export-secret-keys > /shared/nas/gpg/$(hostname)/$(hostname).private.key'

runonall 'for i in $(ls -a /shared/nas/gpg/$(hostname)/$(hostname).private.key); do gpg --import $i; done'

runonall 'for i in $(ls -a /shared/nas/gpg/$(hostname)/$(hostname).private.key); do rm -f $i; done'
 
now each host has the private keys of all the others and you can decrypt any encrypted password file on the shared nas

I should mention when the main script runs, the encrypted password goes to  /shared/nas/gpg/$(hostname)

I KNOW... the private key is supposed to be PRIVATE, but this is for INTERNAL administrative use, and for all intents and purposes the pub key is useless.

This is ONLY to encrypt the password file by the administrators

also added the HOST variable in the initial key creation as below

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation//manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html

```
#!/bin/bash
# gen-keys-wrapper.sh
HOST=$(hostname)
cat >$HOME/gen-keys.sh <<EOF
     %echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
     Key-Type: DSA
     Key-Length: 1024
     Subkey-Type: ELG-E
     Subkey-Length: 1024
     Name-Real: Leadorfollow create root gpg keys on $HOST
     Name-Comment: more free form info here..
     Name-Email: Leadorfollow@foo.bar
     Expire-Date: 0
     Passphrase: abc
     %commit
     %echo done
EOF
gpg --batch --generate-key $HOME/gen-keys.sh
rm -f $HOME/gen-keys.sh
```